# Renaming the tabs in Buddypress

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I have a multisite WP with Buddypress and BP Multi Network.
The sites are being created automatically (data is coming from external system).
The problem is I want to show only the Activity tab in the menu and I want to rename it as well. I have created bp-custom.php and this is its content:

```
    <?php

function bp_change_tabname() {

    global $bp;
    $bp->bp_nav['activity']['name'] = 'Duvar';
    $bp->bp_nav['members'] = false;

}

    add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'bp_change_tabname', 999 );
?>
```

It is not working though. It seems like the content of bp-custom is irrelevant.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To remove a nav item from the navigation array you can use `bp_core_remove_nav_item()`. For example:

```
function my_remove_tabs() {
    bp_core_remove_nav_item( $parent_id );
}
add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'my_remove_tabs' );
```

Where `$parent_id` is the slug of the parent navigation item.

To customise the tab labels, you could use a language file. See the [Customising Labels, Messages and URLs](http://codex.buddypress.org/getting-started/customizing/customizing-labels-messages-and-urls/) article for more info on how and why.

Comment: For some reason this didn't work either...Thanks for the answer though!